# How can I use regex to remove a line from a file with PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am writing an extension to CodeIgniter's language class that will remove a certain language line from a certain file.  The script is provided an array key to determine which file line to remove.  I don't believe I have written my regex properly to detect a config file line.  Here is the cat_names language file:

```
<?php

$lang['cat_123'] = 'Transportation';
$lang['cat_124'] = 'Restaurants';
```

This is my language class extension:

```
public function remove_line($line, $file){

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper('file');

    foreach($this->existing_langs as $lang){

        $lang_contents = read_file($this->lang_path.'/'.$lang.'/'.$file.'_lang.php');

        $new_contents = preg_replace("^$lang\[\$line\] \= (.*?)\\n^", '', $lang_contents);

        write_file($this->lang_path.'/'.$lang.'/'.$file.'_lang.php', 'w+');

    }

}
```

I use the following to call the method that removes lines from the language file:

```
$this->lang->remove_line('cat_123', 'cat_names');
```

Why isn't my preg_replace removing the lines?  Note:  the language file is not read-only.

Comment: Your regex is confusing. Why use caret as delimiter, make it even more confusing :) also do echo your pattern to see if it is escaped and looks like you want it to (variables). To match the `$` literal in double quotes can also be a challenge. And as I understood you want to interpolate `$line` but `$lang` should match literally. Try `preg_replace("/\\\$lang\['$line'\] = (.*)\R/"`...

Comment: Instead of loading the whole file in memory, you should use a generator with a file handler as parameter that filter the line(s) you want to remove and yield the others. To quickly discard lines, you should eventually check the beginning of lines with `strpos` and then to confirm it is the line you want to remove, make an additional check with a pattern if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"^$lang\[\$line\] \= (.*?)\\n^"
"^\\$"."lang\['$line'\] = (.*?)\n^"
```

Your RegEx doesn't work because:

- `$lang` in double quoted string is interpreted as variable (also, this variable doesn't exist);
- You are missing single quotes `'` inside square brackets;
- `$line`, which is a variable, is escaped.

Change it in this way:

```
"^\\$"."lang\['$line'\] = (.*?)\n^"
```

Also note that the `=` does not need to be escaped and the way to escape `$` followed by characters.

In addition, I suggest you use a single-quoted string and set delimiters to another character (in regular expressions `^` means begin of line. Here it works, but can be confusing).

This is single-quote equivalent with different delimiters:

```
'/\$lang\[\''.$line.'\'\] = (.*?)\n/'
```